# Conpressing repeated loops

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I wrote the following code for a [HackerRank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximize-it/problem) involving repeated FOR loops with very similar syntax:

```
x, y = map(int, input().split())

inp = []
for _ in range(x):
    inp.append(list(map(int, input().split()))) 
#I get the rest of the input as a nested list.

while len(inp) < 7:
    inp.append([1, 0])
#Adding dummy values in the list

list = []   
for a in inp[0][1:inp[0][0]+1]:
    for b in inp[1][1:inp[1][0]+1]:
        for c in inp[2][1:inp[2][0] + 1]:
            for d in inp[3][1:inp[3][0] + 1]:
                for e in inp[4][1:inp[4][0] + 1]:
                    for f in inp[5][1:inp[5][0] + 1]:
                        for g in inp[6][1:inp[6][0] + 1]:
                            list.append((a ** 2 + b ** 2 + c ** 2 + d ** 2 + e ** 2 + f ** 2 + g ** 2) % y) 
                            #Given function

print(max(list))
```

> I wonder if there's any way to do this in one go.

PS: I'm an absolute beginner in programming.

Comment: Note that this problem is in the `itertools` section of the site. Maybe there might be an itertool method to help you find the cross-`product()` of the sets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **itertools.product** can simplify the loops a little bits:

```
import itertools as it

K, M = map(int, input().strip().split())

# reading the K lines and appending lists to 'L'
L = []

for i in range(K):
    lst = list(map(int, input().strip().split()))
    L.append(lst[1:])
   

# Looping through Cartesian product 

MAX = -1

for i in it.product(*L):
    MAX = max(sum(map(lambda x: x**2, i))% M, MAX)
    
print(MAX)
```

Comment: Which one do you think is better: writing a program from scratch or using custom libraries? Which one is faster to execute?

Comment: It is a good question. It depends. If you are in learning stage, you could/should try to “invent the wheel” to learn the inner working, but in real world product development, time and performance is essence, so you should take pragmatic approach.